# How do I represent Neo4j relationship properties in my Graphql Schema?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I have a Neo4j DB with relationships that have properties such as [:FRIENDS {since: "11/2015"}]. I need to represent the "since" property in the GraphQl Schema. RELAY has something call "edges" an apparently this is how they implement this feature but I am not using RELAY.....I didn't see anything in Apollo (maybe I missed it). Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: I found the following well written blog that may lead to my answer....https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/explaining-graphql-connections-c48b7c3d6976

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok...so in order to get what I wanted which was to present both the node and the relationship (edge) to graphql I did what I would call a work-around by returning  object.assign(node,relationship)  to graphql....the downside is that I have to define a type nodeRel {} to receive the combined objects but it works. Also, the node and relationship objects can't have similar named properties. I can now answer the question how long John and Mary are friends or what groups John belongs to and how long he has been a member....Schema snippet:

```
    ... memberOf    : [Group]
  groupStatus  : [MemberProfile]
  attended    : [Meeting]
  submittedReport   : [Report]
  post        : [Post]

}

type MemberProfile {
  name          : String
  location      : String
  created       : String
  since         : String
  role          : String
  financial     : Boolean
  active        : Boolean
  }
```

Resolver:

```
groupStatus(voter) {
            let session = driver.session(),
                params = { voterid: voter.voterid },
                query = `
                        MATCH (v:Voter)-[r:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
                        WHERE v.voterid = $voterid
                        RETURN g AS group,r AS rel;
                        `
            return session
                .run(query, params)
                .then(result => {
                    return result.records.map(record => {
                        return Object.assign(record.get("group").properties, record.get("rel").properties)
                    })
                })
        },
```

I hope this help someone else....